# Certificate that a laminar family from a crossing family is maximal

Tags: co.combinatorics

A laminar family $\mathcal{L}$ is a family of sets such that for all $A, B \in \mathcal{L}$, $A \subseteq B$, or $B \subseteq A$ or $A \cap B = \emptyset$. A crossing family $\mathcal{C}$ is such that for all $A, B \mathcal{C}$, $A \cap B \in \mathcal{C}$ and $A \cup B \in \mathcal{C}$. I want to derive a inclusion wise maximal laminar family from a crossing family, i.e.\ generate $\mathcal{L} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{L}$ is inclusion wise maximal. Is there a certificate that shows when I have achieved this?

For instance, if I am generating a maximal laminar family from a ground set $V$ of size $n$, I know that a maximal laminar family has $2n - 1$ elements. Is there something like this for when I generate it from a crossing family?

Comment: Any such family $\mathcal C$ can be represented as the set of the sink parts of the one-way cuts of a digraph. Formally, there exists a directed graph $G=(V,A)$ such that $\mathcal C = \{V'\subseteq V : \delta_{\text{out}}(V')=0\}$. Using this representation, you can check in polynomial time (in the size of the groundset) whether there exists any sink parts which could be added to your laminar family. The latter boils down to shrinking your selected laminar sets appropriately and using some graph traversal algorithm, which should give the certificate you are looking for.